# Android app unable to start activity componentInfo

Tags: android, android-activity, runtime, runtime-error, android-fragmentactivity

app is suppose to display main homepage after splash screen, however, after splash timeout of X secs, the app crashed. Please help, I have attached the error and the following necessary codes.

Error log:

```
01-04 22:48:35.548: E/AndroidRuntime(28912): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-04 22:48:35.548: E/AndroidRuntime(28912): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity   ComponentInfo{com.dapoaugury.channelappdemo/com.dapoaugury.channelappdemo.ChannelAppMainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-04 22:48:35.548: E/AndroidRuntime(28912):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2295)
01-04 22:48:35.548: E/AndroidRuntime(28912):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349)
01-04 22:48:35.548: E/AndroidRuntime(28912):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:159)
01-04 22:48:35.548: E/AndroidRuntime(28912):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316)
01-04 22:48:35.548: E/AndroidRuntime(28912):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-04 22:48:35.548: E/AndroidRuntime(28912):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-04 22:48:35.548: E/AndroidRuntime(28912):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
01-04 22:48:35.548: E/AndroidRuntime(28912):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-04 22:48:35.548: E/AndroidRuntime(28912):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
01-04 22:48:35.548: E/AndroidRuntime(28912):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
01-04 22:48:35.548: E/AndroidRuntime(28912):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
01-04 22:48:35.548: E/AndroidRuntime(28912):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-04 22:48:35.548: E/AndroidRuntime(28912): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-04 22:48:35.548: E/AndroidRuntime(28912):    at com.dapoaugury.channelappdemo.ChannelAppMainActivity.initializeMenu(ChannelAppMainActivity.java:151)
01-04 22:48:35.548: E/AndroidRuntime(28912):    at com.dapoaugury.channelappdemo.ChannelAppMainActivity.onCreate(ChannelAppMainActivity.java:118)
01-04 22:48:35.548: E/AndroidRuntime(28912):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5372)
01-04 22:48:35.548: E/AndroidRuntime(28912):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
01-04 22:48:35.548: E/AndroidRuntime(28912):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
```

Splashscreen Code:

```
 new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                mProgress.setProgress(SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
                Intent i = new Intent(ChannelAppSplashActivity.this, ChannelAppMainActivity .class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }
        }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
```

MainActivity Code(Derived from the error log):

```
public void initializeMenu() {
    ChannelAppMenuAdapter mAdapter = new ChannelAppMenuAdapter(this);

    // Profile
    mAdapter.addHeader("Account");

    // Parse FB Profile data
    // ChannelAppFBDataParser fbParser = new ChannelAppFBDataParser();
    // List<UserProfile> userProfile =
    // fbParser.parse(getApplicationContext());
    // title = userProfile.get(0).getUserName();
    // icon = R.drawable.ic_profile_pic;
    // ChannelAppMenuItemModel userItem = new ChannelAppMenuItemModel(title,
    // icon);
    // mAdapter.addItem(userItem);


    //Case 1:
    title = getIntent().getExtras().getString("name");
    icon = R.drawable.ic_profile_pic;
    ChannelAppMenuItemModel userItem = new ChannelAppMenuItemModel(title,
            icon);
    mAdapter.add(userItem);

    //Case 2:
    /*title = "Settings";
    icon = R.drawable.ic_settings;
    mAdapter.addItem(title, icon);*/

    //Case 2:
    if (isLogin){
        title = "Logout";
        }
    else{
    title = "Login";
    }
    icon = R.drawable.google_icon;
    mAdapter.addItem(title, icon);


    // Channels
    mAdapter.addHeader("Channels");

    //Case 4:
    title = "Exhibition";
    icon = R.drawable.icon;
    ChannelAppMenuItemModel exhibitItem = new ChannelAppMenuItemModel(
            title, icon);
    mAdapter.addItem(exhibitItem);

    //Case 5:
    title = "Galleries";
    icon = R.drawable.icon;
    ChannelAppMenuItemModel galleryItem = new ChannelAppMenuItemModel(
            title, icon);
    mAdapter.addItem(galleryItem);

    //Case 6:
    title = "Artists";
    icon = R.drawable.icon;
    ChannelAppMenuItemModel otherItem = new ChannelAppMenuItemModel(title,
            icon);
    mAdapter.addItem(otherItem);

    mAdapter.addHeader("Products");

    //Case 8:
    title = "Search";
    icon = R.drawable.ic_action_search;
    ChannelAppMenuItemModel searchItem = new ChannelAppMenuItemModel(title,
            icon);
    mAdapter.addItem(searchItem);


    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.drawer);
    if (mDrawerList != null)
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

}
```

Comment: you have a NullPointerException in initializeMenu(), line 151, ChannelAppMainActivity.java. whats at that line?

Comment: Goran that's no fun. Its much more fun to just take a total guess at an answer like me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your didn't give any extras to the intent. So this line

```
title = getIntent().getExtras().getString("name");
```

crashes. Replace with

```
title = getIntent().getStringExtra("name");
```

or supply an extra to the intent called "name"

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, appreciate it very much

Answer (score 1):

The possible answer is mentioned above. I like to share you some info on how to read your log cat window.

1. In Logcat window, choose filter as "Error"
2. Once filtered, at the time of application crash, look at the logs.

> ```
> 01-04 22:48:35.548: E/AndroidRuntime(28912): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
> 01-04 22:48:35.548: E/AndroidRuntime(28912):    at com.dapoaugury.channelappdemo.ChannelAppMainActivity.initializeMenu(ChannelAppMainActivity.java:151)
> 01-04 22:48:35.548: E/AndroidRuntime(28912):    at com.dapoaugury.channelappdemo.ChannelAppMainActivity.onCreate(ChannelAppMainActivity.java:118)
> ```

Go over line by line till you see the term "Caused By"

3. Below the line, search for your application package name.
4. Here it will provide the line in which you might have the issue. Generally, i would recommend you to go over the method completely to find the crash.
5. Once you know the method name, set a debugging point and run your app in debug mode. You will spot the issue easily.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing `tiitle` using `putextra` to mainactivity from splash screen , so it's retreving null.

```
Intent i = new Intent(ChannelAppSplashActivity.this, ChannelAppMainActivity .class);
i.putExtra("name" , "tittlename");
startActivity(i);
```